# mysql JOIN ON column = 'literal string or value' not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

This is the query where I need the results to return only rows with the **userID** = `12345678` the result contains also fields with other **userID**

```mysql
select `a`.*, `b`.`someField` from `a` left join `b` on `a`.`userID` = '12345678'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You join the 2 tables without any linking condition in the ON clause.

Comment: Okay learning sth here, does it mean I must add linking columns and that linking only on literal values cannot work?

Comment: You should join the tables if there exists a relation between them, say a.somecolumn references b.othercolumn and then in the on clause: `on a.somecolumn=b.othercolumn` and finally add a where clause: `where a.userID = '12345678'`

Comment: "return only rows" from what table?  Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Seems like when this is clear it will be a faq.  Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the JOIN condition in the wrong way:

```
SELECT `a`.*, `b`.`someField` 
from `a` left join `b` on a.matchingField = b.matchingField
WHERE `a`.`userID` = '12345678'
```

This is the way to do a proper join. You have a field that is the matchingField that is the link between the records in one table and in the other and the userID is the filtering condition. 
Note that macthingField can also be the same userID. In that case:

```
SELECT `a`.*, `b`.`someField` 
from `a` left join `b` on a.userID = b.userID
WHERE `a`.`userID` = '12345678'
```